# Navigate between rows using excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a simple form using an Excel macro.  This form will be used to input data which will be stored in Sheet2.  If the users want to view the data that has already been saved, they should be able to navigate by using "Next" and "Previous" button.  I am trying to code this logic, though I am able to load the first record after which I am unable to move to the next record.  Below is the code I have used for navigating to next record.

--code for saving the data in Sheet2.

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim ctl As Control

    RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.Name1.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.Account.Value
        .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss") 'date when the record was created
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End With

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
        ctl.Value = ""
    End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

-- code for navigating to next record

```
Private Sub Next1_Click()

    i = i + 1: j = 1

    If i > (Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count - 4) Then
        MsgBox "Max rows Reached"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    Name1.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
    Account.Text = rng.Offset(i, j).Value: j = j + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: What is in your `i` variable? Is it declared as a `Public`?

Comment: yes it is declared as public...

Comment: Have you checked if your values saves correct in sheet2?

Comment: Values save correctly in Sheet2.  What I need help with is for navigating betweeen records when I click on Next button.

Comment: Try to change `i = i + 1: j = 1` to `i = i + 1: j = 0` in `Sub Next1_Click()`. It works for me

Comment: I did that too, but it does not move to the next row... the value displayed is always from the 1st row

Comment: make sure you have `Public i As Long` line __outside__ of all `Sub`'s

Comment: I've posted it as an answer to close the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussions with the OP in comments, it became clear that the reason of a problem is that varible `i` is undeclared. You should use following construction to get it work:

```
Public i As Long

Private Sub Save_Click()
   'your code here
End Sub

Private Sub Next1_Click()
   'your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: He stated in a comment it was declared public

Comment: Ah, I didn't see there were more comments, I've removed my downvote.